# How to make an edit control in fmx transparent and hide its border?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

How can I make an edit control in fmx transparent and at the same time hide the borders of the control, so it will blend into the control in the back?

What I am trying to do is to make a small Notes program where, when I double-click a tabitem, it shows an edit control to change the text of the tabitem.

Answer (score 6):

1. Right click the edit control (let's say Edit1) and click 'Edit Custom Style'.
2. Expand 'edit1style1'.
3. Click background:TActiveStyleObject.
4. Clear the SourceLookup property.

Comment: In step 4 I think you mean SourceLookup. A better alternative would be to simply delete the 'background' object by selecting and clicking the red X button in the structure pane toolbar.

Comment: @MikeSutton I have experienced AVs that way, if multiple controls are given the same style.