# Firemonkey hide bottom border on TEdit

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

When I put a TEdit with Firemonkey (10.4.1) I set the `StyleLookup` to `transparentedit` but on Android I have a ugly white border at bottom, it turn green when I focus the edit.

How can I remove it ?

I try to delete all personalized style but it didn't works, same if I clear the `StyleLookup` in `background` style

The only stuff I do to have a transparent edit is to add a `TRectangle` in my `TEdit`, align `Bottom` with a `Height` of `2px`. I set the `Fill.Color` as the color background, but it's a ugly solution.

Comment: I'm with Fmx 10.4.1, with all style (or without style) I always have the bottom gray/white  border and green when I focus it. I think it's same since XE2.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make an edit control in fmx transparent and hide its border?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22301536/how-to-make-an-edit-control-in-fmx-transparent-and-hide-its-border)

Comment: No I keep the line on my TEdit

Comment: Make sure you are editing Style for Android platform. By default when you start editing style it will load open style for Windows platform even thou your project is set to Android platform.

Answer (score 2):

That line at the bottom is part of the default Android style. You can remove it by modifying the style with the Style Designer.

1. Right click on an Editbox and choose Edit "Custom Style..."
2. You have style structure that looks like this:

[image: Style Designer]

3. In the "background" item there are Bitmap Links. You will see the line in the bitmaps when you open that.

From here there are many ways to get rid that line in the bitmap. But from here I think you will get the idea.

After that, you can set the editbox style StyleLookup to the new name (Edit1Style1)

Comment: The `Edit custom style` is available only on TEdit that are on TForm, my is on TFrame (dont know if it's a bug). Then, I already try the other post and clear the StyleLookup where there is the png file, but I think it's no enought, because when my edit have the style `Edit1Style1`, I keep this line.. even if I delete the background item